# Php ler e inserir JSON no banco Mysql

Tags: php

Estou tentando realizar um insert deste json com php , porem não esta sendo enviado para o banco mysql.

Json que estou tentando ler:

```
{"questionario":[{"id_base":"609","id_usuario":"1","id_pesquisa":"1","id_varejo":"16","respostas":"[{"Pergunta":"Nome","Resposta":"asdasd"},{"Pergunta":"Você é responsável pelo recebimento da entrega de parceria ?","Resposta":"não"}]","data_inicio":"2018-04-20 16:56:58"}]}
```

Código php:

```
public function saveResult($post) {

    $array = $post;

    foreach ($array['questionario'] as $value) {
        $ar['id_usuario']  = $value['id_usuario'];
        $ar['id_pesquisa'] = $value['id_pesquisa'];
        $ar['id_varejo']   = $value['id_varejo'];
        $ar['id_base']     = $value['id_base'];
        $ar['data_inicio'] = $value['data_inicio'];
        foreach($value['respostas'] as $value){
            $ar['Pergunta'] = $value['Pergunta'];
            $ar['Resposta'] = $value['Resposta'];
            try{
            $db = Database::conexao();
            $qry = "INSERT INTO `resultado`(`id_pesquisa`,`id_varejo`,`id_usuario`,`id_base`,`pergunta`,`resposta`,`data_inicio`)VALUES(
              :idPesquisa,
              :idVarejo,
              :iduser,
              :idbase,
              :pergunta,
              :resposta,
              :data_inicio)";

            $statement = $db->prepare($qry);
            $statement->bindValue(':idPesquisa', $value['id_pesquisa']);
            $statement->bindValue(':idVarejo', $value['id_varejo']);
            $statement->bindValue(':iduser', $value['id_usuario']);
            $statement->bindValue(':idbase', $value['id_base']);
            $statement->bindValue(':pergunta', $value['Pergunta']);
            $statement->bindValue(':resposta', $value['Resposta']);
            $statement->bindValue(':data_inicio', $value['data_inicio']);
            $statement->execute();    

         } catch (PDOException $e){
                 echo $e->getMessage();
                 $db->rollBack(); 
         }
        }
    }
}
```

Gera o JSON respostas :

```
var modifiedData = Object.keys(result.data).map(function(qName) {
                                                return {
                                                  Pergunta: qName,
                                                  Resposta: result.data[qName]
                                                }
                                            });
```

Comment: Chega a dar algum erro? eu tomaria cuidado com os nomes das variáveis principalmente  a `$value`.

Comment: o estranho é que não gera erro algum para debugar

Comment: Utilize `$db->errorInfo` para verificar se há erros.

Comment: Também não retorna erro, creio que seja nos foreach... mas não estou conseguindo retornar o dados neles

Comment: Esse json da pergunta retorna inválido: https://ideone.com/XTLSBs

Comment: Verdade rray, esta incorreto, mas mesmo neste formato seria possível ler todos os dados no php? Adicionei o código que gera esta parte do JSON